# Javascript: first attempt at state engine not working

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning about coding and I am starting in javascript, primarily for a class, however I have started going beyond the class, and have tried to learn new things. Right Now I am trying to make a simple game, where it goes from level to level, and my issue is I cannot figure out how exactly to create a state engine, that can jump to the next level and remove the previous from the HTML canvas.

With the script below I am trying to test out using a state engine by making a flashing three box formation.The issue arrises when I want to go to the next case in the switch statement, the previous case's method I called remains.

This is what I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="1024" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var FPS = 60;
var counter = 0;
var currentState = 0;
var intervalTime = 300;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


function init(){
    ticker();
}

function ticker(){
    setInterval(initGame, FPS)
}

function initGame(){
    checkState();
    counter++;
}

function drawBox(x,y){
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

function checkState(){
    switch(currentState){
        case 0:
            console.log("case 0");
            drawBox(0,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 1;
            }
        break;
        case 1:
            console.log("case 1");
            drawBox(50,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 2;
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            console.log("case 2");
            drawBox(100,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 0;
            }
        break;
    }
}


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am new so i apologize if anything above is not formatted properly, or if I am not tackling this the correct way at all.

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what problem you're facing. Do you mean that the state machine doesn't advance state? (That is, the console log doesn't show the right transitions?) Or do you mean that the canvas doesn't update as expected? In the former case, the state machine is indeed broken (although I don't see why that should be). In the latter case, the state machine logic is fine but your rendering logic needs attention. (I suspect that's the case; you need to erase the previous state's box or it will just stay there.)

Comment: Ah sorry yes my issue is that the state does advances, but they stack on top of each other instead of only having 1 at a time. In each case in the switch function i have a function that creates a box, so what I want is for when each case is active that only one 50x50 box is displayed, but each time it advances the box is 50 away from the previous case. I'm using fillRect right now, but I would want to make it so i could insert image's or any method really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect). You can use it in your code like this:

```
function drawBox(x,y){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

That will clear the part of the canvas where the boxes are before each redraw. For more complex applications, you'll probably want to clear the entire canvas.

The complete working code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="1024" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var FPS = 60;
var counter = 0;
var currentState = 0;
var intervalTime = 300;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


function init(){
    ticker();
}

function ticker(){
    setInterval(initGame, FPS)
}

function initGame(){
    checkState();
    counter++;
}

function drawBox(x,y){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,50);
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

function checkState(){
    switch(currentState){
        case 0:
            console.log("case 0");
            drawBox(0,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 1;
            }
        break;
        case 1:
            console.log("case 1");
            drawBox(50,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 2;
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            console.log("case 2");
            drawBox(100,0);
            if (counter === intervalTime){
                counter = 0;
                currentState = 0;
            }
        break;
    }
}


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea i figured I could use clearRect to clear the area if I was only using the fillRect() method, but is there a practical way of updating a more dynamic function, like if instead of having the drawBox() method there were images. Essentially right now I'm trying to make a very basic game and I am trying to make a way to go from level to level using this js.

Comment: @JackSmillie - For a "more dynamic function", I suggest you look into using some sort of sprite engine. Search the web for "javascript sprite" or "javascript canvas animation" and you'll come up with a ton of resources.